# How to add test case to testsuite in xcuitest?

Tags: xctest, swift4.2

I’m trying to run a custom test suite which includes several test cases. For example, I’ve wrote 4 test scripts(test_login_success,test_login_fail,test_register_xxx,test_register_yyy), and I just want to run test_login_* module, how to set the defaultTestSuite and add testcases to it?

Answer (score 0):

The test cases you create belongs to its class. If you want to customise test runs you shall consider updating to the new Xcode 11. The new version of Xcode has test plans feature allowing you to control tests executions better.

Introduction video:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/413/

If you prefer to stay on previous Xcode, you should add schemes for your scenarios.

Also, you can pass tests names in `xcodebuild` shell command.